# Simplifying $\sin(\frac{7A}{2}+15^{\circ})\sin(\frac{3A}{2}-75^{\circ})+\cos(\frac{7A}{2}+15^{\circ})\cos(\frac{3A}{2}-75^{\circ})$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone help me with simplifying this expression:

$$ \sin \left( \dfrac{7A}{2} + 15^{\circ}  \right) \sin \left( \dfrac{3A}{2} - 75^{\circ} \right)  +  \cos \left( \dfrac{7A}{2} + 15^{\circ}  \right) \cos \left( \dfrac{3A}{2} - 75^{\circ} \right) $$

I know that $\sin x \sin y + \cos x \cos y = \cos(x-y)$, but this way I only get the expression:

$$\cos(2A+100^{\circ})$$

The problem is that I have to find the correct solution among the following ones:

- $-2\sin A \cos A$
- $\cos ^2 A - \sin ^2 A$
- $- \sin A$
- $\cos A$

Maybe I shouldn't have used this trigonometric identity but another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your strategy is correct, but you made an arithmetic mistake.

If we set 
$$x = \frac{3A}{2} - 75^\circ$$
and 
$$y = \frac{7A}{2} + 15^\circ$$
then
$$x - y = -2A - 90^\circ$$
so
\begin{align*}
\cos(x - y) & = \cos(-2A - 90^\circ)\\ 
            & = \cos(2A + 90^\circ)
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: You needn't expand $\cos(2A+π/2)$ again. Just note that $\cos(\phi+π/2)=-\sin\phi.$

Comment: @Allawonder  Or I could let the OP figure that out.

Comment: In that case you should just have stopped at $\cos(2A+π/2).$

Comment: @Allawonder Done.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Yes, of course, I know that $\cos(\phi+\dfrac{\pi}{2})=−\sin \phi$ or in other words, the correct answer is now the first one. Just don't know why was not correct to take $x$ and $y$ as I did (obviously opposite of you).

Comment: @AleksandraAsanin  Taking $x$ and $y$ as you did would have saved a step.  I am not completely alert right now.

Comment: @AleksandraAsanin The identity $\cos(x-y)=\cos x\cos y+\sin x\sin y$ is symmetric in its variables, so whichever of the arguments you set to $x$ and $y$ does not matter. You should get the same result if you make no mistakes. You do not include your work, but perhaps you're unconsciously taking $15$ to be $25.$ Such things happen. :)

Comment: @Allawonder oh my God, you're right. I have made the same mistakes two times. God.

Comment: @AleksandraAsanin Glad to have been of help. Such things happen. Another is unconsciously permuting the digits of large integers. Once you come up with such nagging issues where you know it's something elementary, first check these signs, and a few others -- a misplaced $-$ can give one serious headache, I tell you!

Comment: Obviously. I have lost tones of time to simplify the wrong expression :D